# Load rootfs from fit image and signature verification

Tags: openwrt, disk-image, secure-boot

I am new to fit image and secure boot. 
I created fit image using `mkimage` command and added kernel dtb and rootfs into it.

Goals:

1. Need to boot up from fit image kernel rootfs and dtb. 
   I am able to boot up kernel and dtb from the fit image. However I am not getting any clue how to load the rootfs from the fit image and write it to mmcblk.
2. I also need to verify the images i.e kernel rootfs and dtb with some signature. How to do this. Please help me or guide me If I am missing something.

Below is my fitimage configuration:

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
        description = "U-Boot fitImage for Aprisa NEXT/4.14.54+gitAUTOINC+7c0df4bf46/clearfog";
        #address-cells = <1>;

        images {
                kernel@1 {
                        description = "Linux kernel";
                        data = /incbin/("/home/deepak/4RF/release_11/fit_image_pro/zImage");
                        type = "kernel";
                        arch = "arm";
                        os = "linux";
                        compression = "none";
                        load = <20008000>;
                        entry = <20008000>;
                        hash@1 {
                                algo = "sha1";
                        };
                };
                fdt@armada-388-clearfog.dtb {
                        description = "Flattened Device Tree blob";
                        data = /incbin/("/home/deepak/4RF/release_11/fit_image_pro/armada-388-clearfog-pro.dtb");
                        type = "flat_dt";
                        arch = "arm";
                        compression = "none";
                        hash@1 {
                                algo = "sha1";
                        };
                };
                ramdisk@1 {
                        description = "initramfs-main-image";
                        data = /incbin/("/home/deepak/4RF/release_11/fit_image_pro/openwrt-mvebu-cortexa9-device-armada-388-clearfog-pro-rootfs.tar.gz");
                        type = "ramdisk";
                        arch = "arm";
                        os = "linux";
                        compression = "gzip";
                        load = <00000000>;
                        entry = <00000000>;
                        hash@1 {
                                algo = "sha1";
                        };
                };
    };

        configurations {
                default = "conf@armada-388-clearfog.dtb";
                conf@armada-388-clearfog.dtb {
            description = "1 Linux kernel, FDT blob, ramdisk";
            kernel = "kernel@1";
            fdt = "fdt@armada-388-clearfog.dtb";
            ramdisk = "ramdisk@1";

                        hash@1 {
                                algo = "sha1";
                        };
                };
    };
};
```

Please guide me on it and share if any proper document is available for doing the above things.

Answer (score 1):

[image: https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/elce-2014.pdf]

I hope it helps on what you are looking for

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note, however, that attaching images of text is [discouraged](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) because it is often difficult to read, and content will not be available to others "googling" for the problem. If possible, please edit your answer and type the text instead (giving proper credit where necessary).